# Constraint layout with textview

Tags: android, android-layout

How can we write text in Textview in this way in constraint layout  in Android. Here This start from same as below and the next line of description from start of the left of parent without any margin. 
eg.

```
 DEAR, 
      This is description text and we want to write it in textview like paragraph and first line start with some margin and next line with no any margin..
```

Comment: post your code , and problem you are facing with code

Answer (score 0):

Use android design tab to design your xml, and constraint it to anywhere you want

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code in HTML as you desire and can set the text in the textview using ***Html.fromHtml*** :

`textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Dear<br><p>Description</p>"));`

Answer (score 0):

i did it with the SpannableString in android .it helps us to play with string or text like styling and margin and many more things

this is xml code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Dear,"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraint1" />
     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />
```

this is the main code what i what to write in paragraph from first line with some margin`
here,i write our string in strings.xml(spanstring).

MainActivity.java

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            TextView  textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.description);
            SpannableString s = new 
            SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.spanstring));
           int ss= s.length();
            if (ss > 0) {

                s.setSpan(new android.text.style.LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(140, 1), 0, 0,0);
            }
         textView .setText(s);
```